# how to generate a jwt token for rest controller unit testing?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, jwt

I am working on the unit testing for securied restful endpoints. To test it, I need to add the 'Authorization' token in the header.

How can I generate a token for each mockMvc http call? An easier way I can come up with is to call "api/authentication" everytime before each test functions. Then the unit testing will depend on "api/authentication".

Currently, I am using `@WebMvcTest(restController.class)`. Then it only loads the restController, and "api/authentication" won't be available.

How should I handle unit testing for JWT securied rest APIs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this very purpose, there is an annotation @WithMockUser from springframework security. You can find usage here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/test-method.html

```
 @Test
 @WithMockUser(username = "test", password = "test", roles = "USER")
 public void canDeleteYoyo() throws Exception{
     this.mockMvc
         .perform(delete("/admin/templates/1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I handled it.

First inject TestRestTemplate:

```
@Autowired
 private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;
```

Then in @Before method call api/authentication and save jwt token:

```
@Before
public void login() {
        ResponseEntity<UserTokenState> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity("/api/authentication",
                new JwtAuthenticationRequest(email, password), UserTokenState.class);
        this.accessToken = "Bearer " + responseEntity.getBody().getAccessToken();
    }
```